# How can I allow the screen to auto-lock when virtualbox is focused?

Tags: virtualbox, lock-screen, ubuntu-20.04

On my linux (ubuntu 20.04) workstation i usually have a virtualbox VM with windows 10 running, to get access to some work-related things. If I accidentally leave the virtualbox window focused it prevents the screen saver from locking the screen.

Is there a setting, either in ubuntu or in virtualbox, that allows the screen saver to lock the screen when the virtualbox windows is focused?

Comment: Are you using KDE?

Comment: Check the power driver and BIOS on your host machine. I have Windows 7, Kali and Ubuntu running on a Windows 10 Host (VMware Workstation). Any of the 4 machines can have focus and the host screen will turn off normally.

Comment: @harrymc No, I'm using Gnome.

Comment: I do not think it should matter what desktop you use (I use Xfce and Gnome plus Windows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with Gnome on Xorg. Xorg is no longer the default display server for recent versions of Ubuntu. If you switch to a Gnome Wayland session, screenlocking works as expected. It is easy to switch. Just log off, click on your user name on the login screen, and then look down to the lower right of the screen. You will see a button there that allows you to choose "Ubuntu" (for recent versions of Ubuntu) or "Wayland" (for older versions of Ubuntu). Select it, and log in. It will remember your choice next time you log in.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Is it better now?

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple solution to this problem. The cause of the problem is that virtualbox captures the mouse pointer when it is focused and then when the screen-saver tries to capture it as well this fails. The only way to solve this would be to make virtualbox release the mouse pointer a moment before the screen-saver activates but I have not found a way to do this.